# Using a for loop input to rename an object within the loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently trying to rename an input argument by the variable "i" in the following for loop:

```
cd $1
num=$(echo $#)
echo $num
echo $@
echo "This is the next part where I print stuff"
for i in $(seq 2 $num)
        do
        echo $i
        echo ${!i}
        Args_array+=$(printf '${arg_%s[@]}' ${i})
        echo $Args_array
        arg_${i}=$(ls ${!i})
done
```

The output is as follows:

```
4
output_folder /path/to/my.tsv /path/to/my2.tsv /path/to/my3.tsv
2
/path/to/my.tsv
${arg_2[@]}
/var/spool/slurm/d/job6985121/slurm_script: line 23: arg_2=/path/to/my.tsv: No such file or directory
```

But it will not allow me to rename the $2, $3 arguments with "i" like this. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to pass these arguments into R and have to put them in arg_1, arg_2, etc. format.

Comment: Dynamic variable names are messy; why not just use a proper array?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I need to be able to use this function for a wide range of data inputs. My idea is that I would use the dynamic variables so that I wouldn't have to manually change my script when the number of arguments changes (which would be every time I would run the R script these arguments are being passed into. If there is a way to do that, your advice would be greatly appreciated. I am very new to coding and I am not even sure what to google at this point. Thank you again.

Comment: What is `num=$(echo $#)`?? Wouldn't `num=$#` make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what's being attempted with `Args_array` so focusing solely on OP's comment: *'have to put them in arg_1, arg_2'* and skipping `arg_1` since OP's code doesn't appear to care about storing `$1` anywhere; then again, is `R` not capable of processing input parameters from the command line?

One `bash` idea:

```
$ cat testme
#!/usr/bin/bash

num=$#

for ((i=2;i<=$num;i++))
do
    declare args_$i=${!i}
done

for ((i=2;i<=$num;i++))
do
    typeset -p args_$i
done
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ testme output_folder /path/to/my.tsv /path/to/my2.tsv /path/to/my3.tsv
declare -- args_2="/path/to/my.tsv"
declare -- args_3="/path/to/my2.tsv"
declare -- args_4="/path/to/my3.tsv"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Using "declare" worked. The array I am using is because I would like to pass in arguments to an R script as folllows: /Script.R ${arg_2[@]} ${arg_3[@]} ${arg_4[@]}